# Approval Workflow with content targets...?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, approval-process

I have a random question for a workflow & I'm trying to figure out the best way to do it.

I have a content target when someone submits a new 'news' item - say for example, they can select IT, Accounting, HR, Finance, Marketing, etc. etc.

Now I have 1-2 approvers for each of those departments/groups as well.

So, what I want is when someone selects "IT" on the original submission, for it to be sent to the appropriate approvers for that department/group.

Anyone have any suggestions on the best way to handle this? How do I link up the 2 to make that happen? I'd prefer not to have a large string of just IF/ELSE branches, since I'll have close to 25 or so groups by the end. It would be nice to filter them with metadata/columns in a custom list.

Thanks in advance.